# Increment all fields of all objects in a collection pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Hello i would like to increment the field `current_week` of all objects in the collection `tournaments` but i get an error. I have the code:

```
class DataBase:

    def __init__(self):
        self.myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
        self.mydb = self.myclient["MMA_TOURNAMENT"]
        self.tournaments = self.mydb["tournaments"]

    def insert_new_tournament(self, tournament):
        print(tournament.__dict__)
        self.tournaments.insert_one(tournament.__dict__)

    def increment_day(self):
        self.tournaments.update({'$inc': {'current_week' : 1}})
```

and i get the error:

```
TypeError: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'document'
```

when calling the function. I am a beginner in pymongo I really don't know what query I should put there. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a filter as the first parameter to `update_many()`; to update every document your filter is simply `{}`.

```
def increment_day(self):
    self.tournaments.update_many({}, {'$inc': {'current_week' : 1}})
```